# Extends a typescript Type by aliasing a property

Tags: typescript, generics

I try to define a type that can have its properties "aliased" with another name.

```
type TTitle: string;
type Data<SomethingHere> = {
  id: string,
  title: TTitle,
  owner: TPerson,
}

type ExtendedData = Data<{cardTitle: "title", author: "owner"}>;  // or whatever any way to define this type
```

ExtendedData now becomes a type like

```
type ExtendedData = {
  id: string,
  title: TTitle,
  cardTitle: TTitle,
  owner: Person,
  author: Person,
}
```

I intent to describe a graphQL query response that contains aliased fields showing clearly that cardTitle is an alias of title and has the same type.

Comment: How do you intend to convert the string `"title"` to the type `TTitle`? What is the logic that drives this? There can be many type aliases to the string type - how to pick the correct one? And if you have `Data<{ foo: 42 }>` how to pick the type for the `foo` property?

Comment: @VLAZ As long as the value of the provided alias is a keyof `Data` it can be done. Even `42` can be looked up because it is a `PropertyKey` or am I missing something?

Comment: @Behemoth It *can* be looked up. But OP provides no clear instructions in how that should happen. Would `Data<{ bar: "world" }>` also result in the property being typed as `TTitle`? Or is it going to be typed as `TOther` instead? Maybe just as `string`? Would it be based on the key of the property or its value type - as in, is `Data<{cardTitle: "not title"}>;` going to result in a different type? The fact that all of these are possible doesn't explain which of these is correct.

Comment: You're right @VLAZ my question was way too inaccurate, sorry for that ! I tried to describe what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a type `ExtendWithAlias` that accepts two generic arguments: the *base type* (`T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>`) and an object (`A extends { [aliasName: PropertyKey]: keyof T }`) that will augment the *base type* using an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types). 
 Using a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) with [Key Mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) and a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content) we can "lookup" an existing `keyof T` (=`keyof Data`) and add it to our newly computed type with a given alias. Note that TypeScript will directly infer `TTitle` as string.

Caveat: I only tested this with your specific input and some simple variations. There possibly are some flaws or limitations when working with more complex, nested types.

```
type TTitle = string;
type Data = {
  id: string;
  title: TTitle;
};

type ExtendWithAlias<
  T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>,
  A extends { [aliasName: PropertyKey]: keyof T },
> = T & {
  [K in keyof A as A[K] extends keyof T ? K : never]: T[A[K]]  
};

type ExtendedData = ExtendWithAlias<Data, { cardTitle: "title" }>;
// type ExtendedData = Data & {
//     cardTitle: string;
// }
```

---

Some more testing:

```
type Invalid1 = ExtendWithAlias<Data, { cardTitle: "no title" }>;
//                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ cardTitle: "no title"; }' does not satisfy the constraint ...
type Invalid2 = ExtendWithAlias<Data, { cardTitle: {} }>;
//                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ cardTitle: {}; }' does not satisfy the constraint ...

type ValidMultiple = ExtendWithAlias<Data, { cardTitle: "title", idAlias: "id" }>;
// type ExtendedData4 = Data & {
//     cardTitle: string;
//     idAlias: string;
// }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKjCWwA20C8UDOwBO8B2A5gNwBQokUAIgIbDVToDeJUU8AJgFyY77EtRgiFNzjCIpAL6ky4aAFEAHsAh52AdUQALAIJJ41DAB4BMKBGWr2GKACUIAYwD22dkYAK2J5GygA0hAgADRQ1HggAHxBAjrmlmo2jFAA2tT6hgBy1AC2ENye3hC+IAEgALrcANaBTgBmsFCS0REMDQBkUMysyX5seFDVIHVQsYYjPWVxKgkDNfVmAPxQvdx4EABuRRWwyToTk1Ak0iSyFErT7BDsNHSt51aawLrpxjfUIUkO1K4IyHlQACIhH8AY0IqQAPQQwRyKD3NRXN6tJEdZhQ1gYr4-cTcLC4QiQ6GSE7kaAASTw6zSHAAjHd4hptHoDK9aO9OlAsexfiJAXgnIJxKDJOCSOiMRLJVLpTLWAA-BWKpXKlVKsXQmCwgDkn2+3JxfIFwJQAKIjS1UHYTggNn5wEwtHgGFqIEEWmgzjweOo+GAp3JlOp7AATPSLo9niyjG8Ppy9Tz-oxJGDCbK0+mpaqswr1bBtbrsX9uEmzZILVabVA7Q6hM7XU8PU4vTgfXg-f6oAA1IMAWQArkghGAUGGHkyXtG2bGuQnuEChSEOMzDHOOMLRejSXCGYi2QAWZFsqCo3MSmcGvF8VMSpcvXG8Am5yRAA)